# Combine string and element and insert it in innerHtml

Tags: javascript

Imagine I have some element

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

user click between `e` and `l` letter (put caret in this place) , on this click I want insert some `element` between those letters . It will be

```
<p>He<b>Here</b>llo</p>
```

is there any way to make it ?

Code example:

```
  const selection = document.getSelection();
  const parent = selection.baseNode.parentNode;
  const b = document.createElement('b')
  b.innerHTML = 'Here'

  parent.innerHTML = 'he'+ b + 'llo'
```

It will not work as you understand , I need solution for this case. Caret position I can determine

```
selection.focusOffset
```

and this mean that I have to get selection text , and insert on caret position `<b>Here</b>` element. I've also tried to find method to convert element to string , but haven't foudn . I mean `document.createElement(tagName)` make it as string , then I can insert it in text

Comment: Yes, but yoi need to post a [mcve]. I don't want to write all of the JavaScript, too much work, so post some broken JS and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Determining where to put the caret on clicking inside a text node is not an easy problem to solve -- there is a [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretRangeFromPoint) method for it but it's not universally available.    (The rest of the question is trivial, just insert whatever you want once you've figured out where exactly to insert it.)

Comment: Updated little bit , if it will be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `insertNode` method of a Range in the Selection to do it.

Here's a basic example:

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p')
p.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const selection = document.getSelection();
  if(!selection.isCollapsed || !selection.containsNode(p, true))
    return
  const b = document.createElement('b')
  b.innerText = 'here'
  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0)
  range.insertNode(b)
  range.collapse() //unselect inserted text
})
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      const selection = document.getSelection();
      const text = selection.anchorNode.data;
      const parent = selection.baseNode.parentNode;
      const position = selection.focusOffset;

          const html = [
            text.slice(0, position),
            createdElementSpan.outerHTML,
            text.slice(position),
          ].join('');

          parent.innerHTML = html;
```

Seems like it works, `outerHTML` property return string . But also have to find out how to put cursor in correct position

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple solution using DOMParser

```
 let parser = new DOMParser();
 let doc = parser.parseFromString(yourTextHtmlString, 'text/html');
 element.append(doc.body)
```